# Return to page after declining facebook login

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to handle users that don't want to login with facebook after they have already started the process.

Current process:

- Open new browser tab
- Go to URL (mysite.com)
- Click login (launches shadow box)
- Click facebook login button in shadow box (brings user to facebook login page)
- Click the back button (returns user to new tab page, not mysite.com as expected)

It seems redirecting to the facebook login page removes mysite.com from the users history.  How can I make sure users are able to return to mysite.com if they choose to hit the back button to not login with facebook?

I am using the facebook server side login procedure.  And redirecting to obtain "code" from facebook.

this is the function that redirects to the facebook login

```
private void getCode(ServletResponse resp, String app_id, String my_url)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        String dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + 
        app_id + "&scope=email,offline_access&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_url, "UTF-8");
        ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendRedirect(dialog_url);

}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using FB's javascript SDK which does the login/auth via pop-up?

Comment: I ran into problems where my page would load in the login popup instead of the main page.  This seems to be similar to the flow pinterest uses, so I know it's possible.